# SharePoint: How to convert SharePoint search JSON URL to equivalent REST URL

Tags: json, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-search

How can SharePoint search JSON URL be converted to equivalent REST URL?

I need to download the search results and I'm trying to use SharePoint search REST API. To proceed I need equivalent REST URL of JSON as you search using search box & refiners.

Comment: have you tried using this? perhaps the URLs you have will be more useful? https://spservices.codeplex.com/

Comment: @GlennFerrie Thank you but I'm specifically looking for JSON to REST